# How can I make Gimp look more like Photoshop

Tags: gimp

Is it possible to make `Gimp` look more like `Photoshop`?
If so, How can I do this?

Comment: You can make it *look* more like Photoshop, but*work* is really too much. Gimp *isn't* Photoshop. If the looks will suffice, I'll press the button and post.

Comment: jacob-vlijm  ok.

Comment: yeah I found it too, before I found the one below. It didn't seem very useful to me.

Comment: And does the Gimp work like Photoshop after doing this ?

Comment: Thank you, I want to Wordpress theme with gimp, do you think it is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I wouldn't do it (Gimp is Gimp and Photoshop is Photoshop), looking around I found [this](http://doctormo.deviantart.com/art/Gimp-2-8-Photoshop-Tweaks-432736644):

[image]

...which actually did the job quite nicely imo.

#### How to apply

1. Download the zip file from [here](https://github.com/doctormo/GimpPs) (press the green button "Clone or download")
2. Unzip the downloaded folder, make a backup of `~/.gimp-2.8` (`~` stands for your home folder, `~/.gimp-2.8` is a hidden folder by default, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in nautilus to make it visible).
3. Remove "themes" from the original `~/.gimp-2.8` folder and drag the content of the unzipped folder into the original `~/.gimp-2.8` folder.

Done, now on restarting Gimp, it will look like above.
To undo, simply restore the backup of the `~/.gimp-2.8` folder.